# Only 3 columns displaying in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my `Material` Table, I have added  several columns but only 3 columns are being displayed. However, I need all the columns to be displayed. How can I do this ?

I have also shared my code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iwkvy8?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.html).

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 data-table">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> on3 </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> V </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight1">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Q </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> A1 </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight1}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight2">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> A2 </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight2}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight3">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> A3 </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight3}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight4">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> AA </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight4}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight5">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DD </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight5}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">

      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: Adjust the values in the `displayedColumns` array to show the other columns.

Comment: Also `symbol` is not in your datasource.

Comment: @R.Richards Thanks. Just spotted that. May I also know if there's a way to evenly space out each element. At the moment it's all cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

Add matColumnDef in displayedColumns which you want to display in your view, like this :

```
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['position','name','weight1','weight','weight2','weight3','weight4','weight5','symbol'];
```

Comment: Thanks. May I also know if there's a way to evenly space out each element. At the moment it's all cluttered

Comment: try this:
`table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}`